# Output getSegments() array in template

Tags: templating, array, getsegment, output

Is it possible to output a `getSegments()` array in a template to then run conditions on?

I can output one segment fine using `getSegment()`, but if I try to select one or more segments using `getSegments()` it outputs 'Array'.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `getSegments()` returns an array. You can either get one of those segments by using:

```
{% set segments = craft.request.getSegments() %}
{{ segments[0] }}
```

Or loop through all returned segments:

```
{% for segment in craft.request.getSegments() %}
    {{ segment }}
{% endfor %}
```